# How can user change the jre parameter values after the exe is generated in Launch4j?

Tags: java, installer, launcher, flag

Is it possible to change the jre parameter values after the exe file is generated through Launch4j?

The ideal scenario is like this:

The default parameter values are applied when the program is started. However, when the user wants to change some jre parameter values, he goes to a .ini file, MyProgram.ini for example, changes the values there, and the new values will be applied next time the program is started. I think eclipse uses the same way for its memory and some other parameter settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would probably be better off on StackOverflow.

Having said that, have you looked at the section [Additional JVM Options](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Additional_jvm_options) in the docs? I don't know if it works for command-line options, but you can use it to set system properties at least. Another idea is, you know, let the Java program read a configuration file, instead of having Launch4J do it.